# Java 8 streams - How do I manipulate value in a group by result?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects with two `String` fields like

```
Name1, Active
Name2, InActive
Name3, InActive
Name4, Active
```

And I would like to have a

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>>
```

where Active=true and InActive=false.

I tried

```
active = dualFields.stream().collect(
       Collectors.groupingBy( 
           x -> StringUtils.equals(x.getPropertyValue(), "Active")));
```

But I received

```
Map<Boolean, List<DualField>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you can use `partitioningBy`, which is a special case of `groupingBy` (where you are grouping by a `Predicate` into two groups). You can map the objects to the required Strings with `mapping`.

I'm assuming you want the `List<String>` to contain the values of the second property (i.e. not `getPropertyValue()`, which contains "Active" or "InActive"):

```
Map<Boolean,List<String>> map =
    dualFields.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> StringUtils.equals(x.getPropertyValue(), "Active"),
                                                 Collectors.mapping(DualField::getSecondPropertyValue,
                                                                    Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: The code becomes more readable by replacing `StringUtils.equals(x.getPropertyValue(), "Active")` with `x.getPropertyValue().equals("Active")` or, if handling `null` is desired, `"Active".equals(x.getPropertyValue())`… There’s also the standard API method `Objects.equals` which handles `null`, so in either case, there is no need for a 3rd party library to provide redundant methods like `StringUtils.equals`…

Answer (score 4):

If you want your `List<String>` to be composed of `propertyValue`, than:

```
active = dualFields.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy( 
            x -> StringUtils.equals(x.getPropertyValue(), "Active"),
            Collectors.mapping(DualField::getPropertyValue, Collectors.toList());
            ));
```